# Travel to EU with a passport with different number than that on the Bluecard?

Tags: resident-permit, eu, passport, blue-card

I'm asking if there would be any problems for a traveller with such situation:

- The traveller has a valid EU Blue card and passport, travels to his or her home country for a couple of weeks.
- During the stay, he/she need to update some information in the passport, a new passport is issued with a new passport number.
- Now the traveller has a new valid passport and an existing valid EU Blue Card but with his/her old passport number.

The question is: will there be any problem for the traveller to travel back to the EU with the new passport? Does the traveller need any extra documents to issue even before travelling to the home country?